# Passing Domain credentials to Python Flask app on IIS 8.5 server 2012R2 to connect to a database using Trusted Connection

Tags: sql-server, database-connection

I have scoured the net and this site but I cannot seem to get this to work.

This is my first Flask site and right now, I just want to get a Trusted Connection working so i can connect to my databases.

In my app.py i have the following code

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string
import os
import pyodbc

def conn():
    try:
        conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};DATABASE=FP;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Server=MSSQL01; \
        Description=FP;")
        return conn
    except:
        return False

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    username = request.environ.get('REMOTE_USER')
    con = conn()
    template = "<h1>User: {{ con }}</h1>"
    return render_template_string(template, con)

if __name__ == "main":
    app.run
```

I have made the changes to my web.config file as i found.
I know i am missing something, I can use some guidance as to how I can get this trusted connection to work.

thanks

Groundhog

Comment: What program is hosting your web site?  What user is that program running as?

Comment: IIS 8.5 is hosting the site on a Win 2012 server.  I am looking to pass domain credentials to the site so i can access databases.

Comment: Have you created a SQL Server login for the IIS App Pool identity?

Comment: Unfortunately, that isn't allowed in the organization I work for.  Access to the database has to be through domain authentication, they don't have stand alone SQL authentication

Comment: The IIS App Pool identity is a Windows identity, and you would create a Windows Login for the domain account.  EG `create login [somedomain\someuser] from windows`  Is there a login failure message in the SQL Server errorlog?